# can I automatically change the colorscheme when a plugin is loaded in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am using the "Undotree" plugin but I am not happy with the colors. I do not want to change my usual colorscheme for editing purposes. But when I use this plugin,
Chan I change the colorscheme to "mustang" and back to normal when I close the plugin?

I open and close the plugin with

```
nnoremap <F6> :UndotreeToggle<CR>
```

Comment: Well, what did you try?

Comment: I am not an expert on vim plugin developer, like others, I would like your help to even start doing this. At the moment I just manually change the colorscheme.

Comment: You don't need to be an expert to try to add another command to that mapping.

Comment: Add the keystrokes used for changing the colorscheme after the `<CR>` is what I would try.

Comment: You can add keystrokes to change the colorscheme but it wont revert back. I somehow need to restore as well on a second press

Comment: Did you consider highlighting the syntax groups introduced by UndoTree to your taste? `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim` to see the current active syntax groups you have.